# Need to disable only vertical scrolling in web view android

Tags: android, webview, vertical-scrolling

In XML, I given **android:scrollbars="none"** to web view

```
<WebView
    android:id="@+id/wvProgress"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

In java file,

```
wvProgress.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
```

but, still some vertical scrollbar is not disable and some extra white space is display below web view.
[image: Show screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**After tried multiple ways, finally I found solution for my questions - show only horizontal scroll and remove vertical scroll in webview.**

First, I have **set height and width of webview** which I required.Then **put webview in horizontal scrollview**. So,I found vertical scrolling is remove and only horizontal scrolling is available. **For better UI  performance and scrolling I put horizontal scrollview in framelayout.**

My Source code show below:-

```
 <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <HorizontalScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scrollbars="none">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <WebView
                        android:id="@+id/wvProgress"
                        android:minHeight="0dp"
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/_800dp"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/_300dp" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </HorizontalScrollView>

        </FrameLayout>
```